# How to create an executable link to jar file?

Tags: java, symlink, multiple-instances

I'm developing a Java GUI-less application and I need to test its behavior running multiple instances of it at the same time.

I created this folder structure

```
Testing
  ├──> Instance1
  │      ├──> App.jar
  │      └──> cfg.properties
  ├──> Instance2
  │      ├──> App.jar
  │      └──> cfg.properties
  ├──> Instance3
  │      ├──> App.jar
  │      └──> cfg.properties
  └──> Instance4
         ├──> App.jar
         └──> cfg.properties
```

The `cfg.properties` file is different for each folder, but the `App.jar` files are just copies of the .jar generated by the IDE. The problem with this is I need to manually replace each .jar, each time I make any change to the original.

Is there any way to have something like a link to the original .jar file instead of real copies of it, so all of them auto update each time I change the original one? (A solution in Windows would be great, but any Linux trick would also work for me)

Comment: does your OS support symbolic links?

Comment: @karakfa Windows? yes. But it wont let me to execute it. I get "Error: Unable to access jarfile App.jar". Haven't tried in Linux yet, though

Comment: not sure on Windows, the extensions might be playing some role, not sure; it should work trivially on Linux.

Comment: how are you running your tests? are you using java -jar command? can you modify app.jar to receive cfg path as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move App.jar into new folder and specify app.jar path in classpath java argument

```
Testing
  ├──> Jar
  │      ├──> App.jar
  ├──> Instance1
  │      └──> cfg.properties
  ├──> Instance2
  │      └──> cfg.properties
  ├──> Instance3
  │      └──> cfg.properties
  └──> Instance4
         └──> cfg.properties
```

Test instance 1

```
    cd  Testing/Instance1
    java -jar -cp ../Jar/App.jar
```

in this way you don't need a jar in each instance folder